# Line plot using ggplot on replicated data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, replicate

```
I am trying to do a line plot using ggplot on my replicated data. There are five data sets and each data has five replicates as a1, a2, a3, a4, a5. Similarly for data b I have b1, b2, b3, b4 and b5. So for data c, d and e. The header of the file is:
```

window,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,a5,b5,c5,d5,e5

input data file: sample.csv

window,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,a5,b5,c5,d5,e5 1,0.5119139270063112,0.47791314579835403,0.5113649113621064,0.4768479198351406,0.4781196611442378,0.4904659238214216,0.4759001987193641,0.5045061445003193,0.46595531689590725,0.46895114448250247,0.5157597562047104,0.4626524507763233,0.5119529472920509,0.46679831665520277,0.4753377144386213,0.5124522484203766,0.47866380278778836,0.5043826069075172,0.46449419260825464,0.4653139518854975,0.5154697074773474,0.48248274005573855,0.5050305296130029,0.49623759342174706,0.4722137779263525 2,0.5056365340283908,0.46758449834277266,0.49619468151650975,0.4665775998779715,0.4651027722705412,0.48324302406609954,0.46548949368747544,0.4881297422328141,0.45664340325880926,0.4569799185976083,0.5095802510067207,0.45217566931579356,0.4962174884734367,0.4541139099188144,0.4622091078391724,0.5054415475649608,0.4675162679265218,0.48893015580115085,0.4526988654743916,0.4543939472080714,0.5082810308114483,0.47333995451366645,0.4892583331670169,0.4867492749442232,0.4607009344412719 3,0.5029917780963806,0.4506082336787582,0.48882506001136095,0.4618629443073386,0.4617223672843401,0.48114715217930987,0.44907838904575925,0.4839223049902416,0.4511580881044095,0.45572089865752335,0.5080864892752102,0.4350796753702363,0.49098197740136734,0.4519287009416857,0.4615085603108922,0.5025292480080604,0.45217319967673864,0.4824742730108645,0.4495284602643657,0.4496526917343683,0.5050565730983835,0.4551333544455344,0.4831129861925819,0.48318507707190794,0.4591711467216344 4,0.4860720719602721,0.43752609389709796,0.47703314450655865,0.44903659289442394,0.45218688630860454,0.4651313683779647,0.44235562588716304,0.4720672218558838,0.4396877162058581,0.4426667739398868,0.48880911805420235,0.4267229992446821,0.47998318074643315,0.44049405993827934,0.451073514863146,0.48367668084996757,0.44193057677912956,0.4711244386359243,0.439707452759909,0.43988457507554785,0.48873634973006397,0.4441146906280695,0.4715323550100301,0.4757715584753876,0.44871908674391586 5,0.4807988674178904,0.4281526905980928,0.47586024905478386,0.4427077017757281,0.44957536591323116,0.4601169309591469,0.4326716980374979,0.47274778256960215,0.43049870633801507,0.4421312487544498,0.4844120076485326,0.417411296248015,0.47940558916162573,0.4321717759744735,0.4506770232182257,0.4794851393888802,0.43127390836070945,0.47045878954792775,0.4321381904939295,0.43552106233750815,0.48281846812897367,0.4335871681888636,0.47182093520357893,0.469747294370466,0.44414938500789214 6,0.46697868449038515,0.4110182141540053,0.4665989235017278,0.42965099167109877,0.43365693016694545,0.44868681383467235,0.41432513148417094,0.4615368625997305,0.4191419469166949,0.4249355380683784,0.46957399329423505,0.4011386609854494,0.46996089286953063,0.4212430433482374,0.43391126996072205,0.4662145334023028,0.4116292029207663,0.46046649791928934,0.4179878776915891,0.42242058699267215,0.47148645813781453,0.4175979061579417,0.46091994598441166,0.4559704065436049,0.42670443571750466 7,0.4539585432996916,0.4027164860276206,0.4571606009190912,0.4213806501748478,0.42696015461576975,0.43440389748725805,0.40456857455462664,0.45190755377965985,0.4137397619863431,0.41555105482939025,0.45478232248259287,0.3923155126953304,0.4600184223020188,0.4154714754213875,0.426731702076013,0.45321786256641894,0.4028526788819317,0.4515137517994161,0.41197026032900613,0.4167327687345927,0.4602469173245063,0.4054732255216844,0.4526326217432182,0.45132121321665086,0.4201850569025235 8,0.4500307501501692,0.40390978328355526,0.4431832309492467,0.40482053867483664,0.4202986891257512,0.4333109973987116,0.407973565414009,0.43940157378549466,0.39729271359467316,0.4124600814133578,0.45372705610740427,0.38786532198574536,0.44962703798764053,0.3976432921342444,0.42040488370861245,0.44826397790043493,0.41102914472852703,0.44033344026346616,0.39413846587704454,0.40858434464233323,0.4501347092728965,0.39886987931157086,0.44001010571256627,0.43494571104007607,0.41615579336324593 9,0.4330092047324554,0.3741173358623737,0.4335645495527913,0.39883730440357434,0.40392560876927674,0.41868374766231153,0.37326716723050685,0.4322724319330117,0.3902581394607779,0.3960105153714149,0.4346725123572353,0.3611578879266523,0.43916476550749584,0.39047856335166836,0.4039376739885303,0.43303799318380637,0.37606248214759563,0.4313202734544609,0.38419036223588765,0.3962166977665812,0.43695250227993837,0.3740277728117008,0.4312086862781132,0.42687187408061195,0.40068898761510013

I tried the below code to plot my data when not in replicates with header as:
window,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1

input: sample2.csv window,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1 1,0.5119139270063112,0.47791314579835403,0.5113649113621064,0.4768479198351406,0.4781196611442378 2,0.5056365340283908,0.46758449834277266,0.49619468151650975,0.4665775998779715,0.4651027722705412 3,0.5029917780963806,0.4506082336787582,0.48882506001136095,0.4618629443073386,0.4617223672843401 4,0.4860720719602721,0.43752609389709796,0.47703314450655865,0.44903659289442394,0.45218688630860454 5,0.4807988674178904,0.4281526905980928,0.47586024905478386,0.4427077017757281,0.44957536591323116 6,0.46697868449038515,0.4110182141540053,0.4665989235017278,0.42965099167109877,0.43365693016694545 7,0.4539585432996916,0.4027164860276206,0.4571606009190912,0.4213806501748478,0.42696015461576975 8,0.4500307501501692,0.40390978328355526,0.4431832309492467,0.40482053867483664,0.4202986891257512 9,0.4330092047324554,0.3741173358623737,0.4335645495527913,0.39883730440357434,0.40392560876927674

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.csv("sample2.csv")
head(df)
window <- df$window
window
a1 <- df$a1
a1
b1 <- df$b1
b1
c1 <- df$c1
c1
d1 <- df$d1
d1
e1 <- df$e1
e1
ggplot() +
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=window, y=a1, color="a1"))+
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=window, y=b1, color="b1")) + 
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=window, y=c1, color="c1")) + 
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=window, y=d1, color="d1")) + 
geom_line(data=df,aes(x=window, y=e1, color="e1")) +
scale_color_manual(name="color", values = 
c("a1"="red","b1"="blue","c1"="yellow","d1"="black","e1"="green"))+
xlab("window") +
ylab("values")
```

Comment: How can I share my input file?

Comment: It works. Thank you. How can the color legend be a, b, c, d, e instead of a1, b1, c1, d1, e1. The data is plotted based on the values of five replicates for each data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `data.table::melt` your data beforehand and use `variable` column as x like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df <- read.csv("sample2.csv")
measure_vars <- paste0(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), times = 5), rep(1:5, each = 5))
df <- melt(data.table(df), id.vars = "window", measure.vars = measure_vars, variable.factor = F)
df[, color_var := substr(variable, 1, 1)]
ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = df,aes(x = window, y = value, color = color_var, group = variable))+
    scale_color_manual(
        name="color", 
        values = c("a" = "red", "b" = "blue", "c" = "yellow", "d" = "black", "e" = "green")
    ) +
    xlab("window") +
    ylab("values")
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works. Is it possible to have color legends as a, b, c, d, e instead of a1, b1, c1, d1, e1 because the plotted data represents five replicates (a1, a2, a3,a4, a5 represents five replicates of a, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 are five replicates of b and so on...)

Comment: To better understand please answer me this: do you want to have 1 line plot with 5 lines (a to e) or do you want 1 line plot with 25 lines (a to e, 1 to 5)?

Comment: 1 line plot with 25 lines (a to e, 1 to 5). In this case all lines will represent invidual reps (a1, a2, a3, a4......e1,e2,e3,e4,e5.

Comment: I edited the code. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: could you please explain: df[, color_var := substr(variable, 1, 1)]

Comment: Sure. If we melt the data we get column `variable` with values as a1, a2, ..., e4, e5 but we want to color lines based on category (a to e) which in this case is always first letter. `substr` will extract part of the string, in that case from column `value` from 1st to 1st character. Then we use this column for `color` in `aes`.

Comment: let say if these variables are alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, abc etc. I mean with different lengths then what changes can one make in the code?

Comment: Assuming the variable is 'something' followed by one digit you might go with ` df[, color_var := substr(variable, 1, nchar(variable) - 1)]`

Comment: Thank you Dominik. Also, I think removing variable.factor = F in the above code does not make any difference.